# ANLTR4 C# BailErrorStrategy

Tags: c#, antlr4

I'm trying to be strict in catching all lexical errors by inheriting from my main project's lexer, but cannot figure out how to attach my class:

```
public class BailLexer : LISBASICLexer
{
    public BailLexer(ICharStream input) : base(input)
    {
    }

    public override void Recover(LexerNoViableAltException e)
    {
        IToken token = e.OffendingToken;
        string message = string.Format("error at line {0}, position {1} at {2} ", token.Line, token.Column, token.Text);
        throw new ParseCanceledException(message);
    }
}
```

to my lexer:

```
AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(stream);
LISBASICLexer lexer = new LISBASICLexer(inputStream);
lexer.RemoveErrorListeners();
lexer.AddErrorListener(new BailLexer(inputStream));
```

When I code this, the compiler gives me this error:

```
Error   7   The best overloaded method match for 'Antlr4.Runtime.Recognizer<int,Antlr4.Runtime.Atn.LexerATNSimulator>.AddErrorListener(Antlr4.Runtime.IAntlrErrorListener<int>)' has some invalid arguments C:\prj\LISC-ANTLR\LISC-ANTLR\FormWorkbench.cs   63  6   LISC-ANTLR
```

What sort of mechanism do I need to connect my custom error listener to my lexer?  My attempts at converting Java examples have so far been fruitless.  I'm trying to catch lexical errors as TestRig does, for example:

```
line 6:6 token recognition error at: 'L'
line 6:7 token recognition error at: 'O'
line 6:8 token recognition error at: 'G'
```

Can anyone offer me an example?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simple: I needed to **replace my lexer** with my custom one, not add a listener to it:

```
AntlrInputStream inputStream = new AntlrInputStream(stream);
BailLexer lexer = new BailLexer(inputStream);
```

Still didn't trap the errors I was hoping it would, but at least I have strict lexing now.